# My keyboard layout keeps getting set to French?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lightdm, xfce, keyboard-layout

I have both XFCE and i3wm installed on my computer. Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit.

My mouse stopped working and I was too lazy to get another one, so I was trying to mash my keyboard to find the shortcut to change the desktop environment. Somehow in this process I managed to change my keyboard layout to French.

I have already tried checking the settings in `/etc/default/keyboard` and running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but the file already contains US 105-key and the command didn't fix the problem. I can change it back to English in XFCE but it resets on the login screen.

What key could I have hit to change my keyboard layout to French? How do I change it back?